# Show presence information in Outlook 2013 from lync instead of jabber

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2013, jabber, lync-2013

I use lync messaging and it integrates with Outlook to show the presence information. But, since I installed jabber, outlook is now showing presence info from jabber. How do I change this back to lync?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution [here](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/12316076/jabber-phone-mode-breaks-presence-outlook-lync) works for me. The registry entries need to be updated. The catch is that this needs to be done every time Outlook is restarted.

Answer (score 0):

How does your settings in Lync look under "Personal" -> Personal Information Manager

[Personal Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/auxuu.png)

I have not used Jabber, but it might have a settings panel like this one, where your will be able to disable the integration with Outlook.

Comment: No, there isn't any such setting